# Completely compromised, but how?

Tags: samsung, stock-android, samsung-galaxy-s

I'm hoping a few geniuses out there can  lend there wisdom, I'm at a complete loss. Or maybe I'm the simple type.

I would like to assume I'm "hacked" but the situations I've been through lead me to believe what I'm dealing with is something a little different?

I'm seeing the strangest activity on my mobile device, as well as my fiances. And I believe whatever is plaguing our phones is also effecting my PC as well. Went from Note 8's which saw some of this bizaar behavior to two S10's for 2 weeks. After seeing the same things but worse in the S10's we actually switched carriers to another set of S10's and are having the exact same issues.

I noticed I was being properly updated either. And I couldnt view the previous update info which I should be able. And when we dropped our previous carrier the phone was able to update properly after about a day of being deactivated. Then with our new carrier, they rolled me back to the Feb edition if SE for Android status after already giving me March.

[image: I definitely didnt say what it says I did, that appeared out of nowhwere]

[image: Odd icon on notification?]

[image: This error has only appeared since the issues began, on 3 separate devices]

[image: Just trying to use SMS Backup, but cant entirely. I dont have advanced messaging?]

[image: No sandbox....]

[image: Alipay...?]

Comment: have you tried a security check on your google account?

Comment: You have to describe the screenshots, without the knowledge what you did and why you think something shown on the screenshot is strange we can't help you.